# splitting string and counting tokens in c

Tags: c, string, split

I have a text file that contains multiple strings that are different lengths that I need to split into tokens.
Is it best to use `strtok` to split these strings and how can I count the tokens?

Example of strings from the file

```
Emma Stone#1169876#COMP242#COMP333#COMP336#COMP133#COMP231
Emma Watson#1169875#COMP336#COMP2421#COMP231#COMP338#CCOMP3351
Kevin Hart#1146542#COMP142#COMP242#COMP231#COMP336#COMP331#COMP334
George Clooney#1164561#COMP336#COMP2421#COMP231#COMP338#CCOMP3351
Matt Damon#1118764#COMP439#COMP4232#COMP422#COMP311#COMP338
Johnny Depp#1019876#COMP311#COMP242#COMP233#COMP3431#COMP333#COMP432
```

Comment: `strtok` is the way to go for this one. Read the [Documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) if you are unsure how it works. Make sure to use `strtok_r` if it needs to be thread safe. `strtok` returns NULL when no more tokens are found. This is how you can count the amount of tokens.

Comment: @vsr: `strtok()` is rarely the right tool for anything. In this case, it is unclear whether a sequence of `##` is equivalent to a single `#` and whether a `#` appearing at the beginning or end of line is to be ignored... `strtok()` makes strong assumptions for these cases that may not be the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, using [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) is a good solution to the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char line[] =
        "Emma Stone#1169876#COMP242#COMP333#COMP336#COMP133#COMP231";

    char *p;
    int num_tokens = 0;

    p = strtok( line, "#" );

    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        num_tokens++;

        printf( "Token #%d: %s\n", num_tokens, p );

        p = strtok( NULL, "#" );
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Token #1: Emma Stone
Token #2: 1169876
Token #3: COMP242
Token #4: COMP333
Token #5: COMP336
Token #6: COMP133
Token #7: COMP231
```

However, one disadvantage of using `strtok` is that it is destructive in the sense that it modifies the string, by replacing the `#` delimiters with terminating null characters. If you do not want this, then you can use [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *const line =
        "Emma Stone#1169876#COMP242#COMP333#COMP336#COMP133#COMP231";

    const char *p = line, *q;
    int num_tokens = 1;

    while ( ( q = strchr( p, '#' ) ) != NULL )
    {
        printf( "Token #%d: %.*s\n", num_tokens, q-p, p );
        num_tokens++;
        p = q + 1;
    }

    printf( "Token #%d: %s\n", num_tokens, p );
}
```

This program has identical output to the first program:

```
Token #1: Emma Stone
Token #2: 1169876
Token #3: COMP242
Token #4: COMP333
Token #5: COMP336
Token #6: COMP133
Token #7: COMP231
```

Another disadvantage with `strtok` is that it is not [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) or [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), whereas `strchr` is. However, some platforms provide a function [`strtok_r`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), which does not have these disadvantages. But that function does still has the disadvantage of being destructive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should use `strtok` to split these strings.

On

> how can I count the tokens

You can simply add a counter inside `while` and increment it by one in each iteration to get the total number of tokens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char string[] = "Hello world this is a simple string";
  char *token = strtok(string, " ");
  int count = 0;

  while (token != NULL) {
    count++;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  printf("Total number of tokens = %d", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`strtok()` is rarely the right tool for anything. In this case, it is unclear whether a sequence of `##` is equivalent to a single `#` and whether a `#` appearing at the beginning or end of line is to be ignored...

`strtok()` makes strong assumptions for these cases that may not be the expected behavior.

Furthermore, `strtok()` modifies its string argument and uses a hidden static state that makes it unsafe in multithreaded programs and prone to programming errors in nested use cases. `strtok_r()`, where available, solves these issues but the semantics are still somewhat counterintuitive.

For your purpose, you must define precisely what is a token and a separator. If empty tokens are allowed, `strtok()` is definitely not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write your own function to handle this quite trivial split:

```
char **split(char *str, char **argv, size_t *argc, const char delim)
{
    *argc = 0;
    if(*str && *str)
    {
        argv[0] = str;
        *argc = 1;
        while(*str)
        {
            if(*str == delim)
            {
                *str = 0;
                str++;
                if(*str) 
                {
                    argv[*argc] = str;
                    *argc += 1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            str++;
        }
    }
    return argv;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *argv[10];
    size_t argc;
    char str[] = "Emma Stone#1169876#COMP242#COMP333#COMP336#COMP133#COMP231";

    split(str, argv, &argc, '#');

    printf("Numner of substrings: %zu\n", argc);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("token [%2zu] = `%s`\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b1aarnfWs

Remarks: same as strtok it requires `str` to me modifiable. `str` will be modified.